# Why does IE9 ignore these javascript links but produces no errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, magento, prototypejs

At the bottom of this [Magento product page](http://portodivino.com.br/casa-rivas-carmenere-2008) you can see three tabs (Additional Info, Description and Tags) but it is impossible to switch between them in Internet Explorer 9 (even if I add the site to the trusted site group). The IE Javascript console (via F12) doesn't show one single error or warning.

**What is going on?**

Comment: the issue could be `javascript:void(0)` in the links. I did a quick search and it seems a lot of people are reporting links that use that don't work in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this on a site I did last year - this isn't a new site, right? Some used to use the technique of forcing IE9 into IE8 mode using;

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

but I fixed my issue using this thread;

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/219259/#t328876

Reposted here for link rot, in `template/catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml`

you remove the ordered list (ol);

```
showContent: function(a) {
    var li = $(a.parentNode), ul = $(li.parentNode);
    ul.select('li', 'ol').each(function(el){
```

Would become;

```
showContent: function(a) {
    var li = $(a.parentNode), ul = $(li.parentNode);
    ul.select('li').each(function(el){
```

(I've not copied the full function out, it's only that last line that changes).

Hope that helps you too.

**EDIT** - Yes I checked - the file and directory structure for the collateral info like this has since gone, but for CE 1.5 there was a tabs.phtml file in product/view/